# How i can get so smooth sculpt

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

im watching YanSculpts on youtube and i can't see poligons in his Sculpt and i want my sculpt to look like his. Is it different matcap or sth else?[image: YanSculpt's sculpt]

[image: My Sculpt]

Comment: Did you try setting the object's shading to smooth?

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla It worked, thank you. Didn't know smooth shading works in sculpt mode too

Answer (score 3):

In object mode set the shading to smooth in order to avoid seeing the individual polygons of the mesh when sculpting.

**Blender 2.80:**
To do this open the "Object" menu in the 3D viewport header and choose "Shade Smooth"

**Blender 2.79:** 
In the 3D viewport press  <kbd>T</kbd>  to show the toolbar. In the "Tools" tab select "Smooth" under the Shading section.

Alternatively you can search for the operation "Shade Smooth" or just "Smooth" by pressing  <kbd>Space</kbd>  in 2.79 or  <kbd>F3</kbd>  in 2.8

**Note** Dynamic Topology has its own Smooth shading option for Sculpt mode which overrides this setting from other modes and should be set separately.

Comment: Note that Dynamic Topology has its own Smooth shading option for Sculpt mode which overrides this setting from other modes and should be set separately.